# What is a translation matrix in the direction of v= (1, 2, 3)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not even looking for an answer to this specific question. I just don't know what this means. I'm in online classes and my professor just skipped over this in his lectures and never brought it up. Meanwhile there are certainly questions about it on the test as I've taken it once and get a 2nd go around. I'd love if he answered me, but I'm 0/3 on that. I tried googling this or even just "What is a translation matrix given a direction vector" and nothing mentions translation matrices. I have not seen a similar example on google in any top result I try searching for. Is there some kind of formula for this? I apologize if this is just some other way of saying something, but my professor seems to have dropped his microphone in water(joke) and has a heavy accent on top of that. I've basically been copying formulas down and searching online for explanations. So far, but this seems to be the wall of walls.

As I'm typing this, this is the best explanation I got: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvevHXITVG4

EDIT: Most questions on here about Translation Matrices are way above my pay grade. Example: [Find Rotation and Translation Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230290/find-rotation-and-translation-matrix)

Comment: Translation is not a linear map. If you’re doing projective geometry or computer graphics, one encodes it as a linear map in one dimension higher.

Comment: @Jacob To give a more specific followup to Ted's comment: if you're using the standard computer graphics trick of [representing affine transformations with matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation) with the help of projective coordinates, then the matrix associated with this translation is
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&2\\0&0&1&3\\0&0&0&1}.
$$